# WebKit authentication user name and password C#

Tags: c#, authentication, webkit

I have used [a] WebKit engine but I have a problem with the authentication box: it is not showing. For example, when I go to `http://192.168.0.1/` (router settings) [it] must show box authentication and require a username and password to continue.

But when I browse on website using this code:

```
webKitBrowser1.Navigate("192.168.0.1");
```

The authentication box is not show and WebKit page is staying blink :(.

What must I do, to input user name and password?

http://s13.postimg.org/b33giafpj/3h35h3t.png

Comment: Don't know if c# webkit engine supports authenticate signal or similar. Generally, engine won't show its dialog box and is left up to individual application to show the dialog or provide credentials in some other way. http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html#WebKitWebView-authenticate

Comment: so, what i can must do :(

Comment: so another way to input user name and password ?

Comment: plz of u can write to me code can i input username and password to webkite without show dialog box

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with C# bindings of webkit at all. I even don't know which one you are using - I think there are couple of them. Look up the documentation to see if it exposes anything